# No output from headphones jack (occasionally), although system displays output

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I am having an issue where I will start or restart my PC and suddenly no audio comes from the headphones jack. This only happens occasionally, and I don't know the cause. My PC speakers work fine every time. `pavucontrol` shows my headphones as `plugged-in`, with the output db's moving and all, but no output (I've tried multiple headphones and audio sources).

I believe that I have all dependencies for alsa and pulseaudio installed..0

I tried running `alsamixer` and played with the volume controls, but still no sound. It says my chip is `Realtek ALC3232`, which has a number of settings that work when I toggle mute and adjust the volume settings for the speakers, although adjusting the headphones section does not have any effect on the headphones output. This is consistent with the `pavucontrol` interface. I also have an `Intel Haswell HDMI` card, which does not have any adjustable settings, just `S/PDIF`, `S/PDIF 1` and `S/PDIF 2`, none of which I can toggle.

Here is some of my system info:

```
[lucas-pc]/home/lucas$ uname -a
Linux lucas-pc 4.1.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 15 08:30:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[lucas-pc]/home/lucas$ pacman -Qs alsa
local/alsa-lib 1.0.29-1
    An alternative implementation of Linux sound support
local/alsa-utils 1.0.29-1
    An alternative implementation of Linux sound support
local/zita-alsa-pcmi 0.2.0-2
    The successor of clalsadrv, provides easy access to ALSA PCM devices.
[lucas-pc]/home/lucas$ pacman -Qs pulse
local/libcanberra-pulse 0.30-5
    PulseAudio plugin for libcanberra
local/libpulse 6.0-2
    A featureful, general-purpose sound server (client library)
local/pavucontrol 3.0-1
    A GTK volume control for PulseAudio
local/pulseaudio 6.0-2
    A featureful, general-purpose sound server
[lucas-pc]/home/lucas$
```

Any suggestions or insight?

Comment: I have the same chip and exactly those same results. I tried playing with ordering of cards (both the hdmi & normal HD card are handled by snd-hda-intel) but that didn't help either. I would say that because the EQ bands are moving there should be sound - but there's obviously an issue.
One line in dmesg seems weird:
`[ 3815.852263] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input55`
which looks like headphone is taken as input

Answer (score 0):

So this is not going to be an exact answer but it might help you find out more. I managed to make mine work by using hdajackretask (part of alsa-tools).

I tried a couple of things and this firmware config seems to work:

```
# cat /lib/firmware/hda-jack-retask.fw 
[codec]
0x10ec0292 0x17aa220c 0

[pincfg]
0x12 0x90a60130
0x13 0x40000000
0x14 0x90170110
0x15 0x0321101f
0x16 0x21211010
0x18 0x411111f0
0x19 0x21a11010
0x1a 0x0321102e
0x1b 0x411111f0
0x1d 0x40738105
0x1e 0x411111f0

[model]
auto
```

And to make this load on reboot:

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/hda-jack-retask.conf 
# This file was added by the program 'hda-jack-retask'.
# If you want to revert the changes made by this program, you can simply erase this file and reboot your computer.
options snd-hda-intel patch=hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw
```

You will likely need to play around with different configurations. I might have just been lucky...

More information about options is in HD-Audio docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio.txt